# Tweetdeck: Sort columns by "most recent first"

Tags: sorting, tweetdeck

This seems like a very simple question, but neither Google or the Tweetdeck manual can answer it.

How can I sort columns by date in tweetdeck?

My columns seems to have no order at all, mentions and tweets from 80 days ago are followed by the ones from yesterday. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

They just fixed the browser clients (restart browser to fix). For TweetDeck for Mac, make sure that "Scheduled" is not your right-most column.